# Is there any tool to measure the quality of a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Is there any tool to find/measure the quality of a Makefile which would represent the problems in the Makefile(like missing dependencies,discrepencies etc..) if any, graphically?
For Example, I have a bunch of makefiles which are called/invoked from a top-level Makefile, where build is run from the top-level makefile. I want to know if there is any tool to measure the quality of the makefile(in this case, top level makefile),like how good, bad or ugly things are.

My expectation: If there is any such tool to measure the quality of the makefile, the tool should be able to
1) report the issues in the makefile.
2) ideally graph the results from point# 1.

Below code is the simple scenario of Recursive makefile, which invokes sub-makefiles.

```
petry@als02%ls 
ant  bee  Makefile

petry@als02% cat Makefile

MODULES= ant bee
all:
        for dir in $(MODULES);do $(MAKE) -C $$dir;done
.PHONY:clean
clean:
        rm -rf ./ant/main.o ./bee/parse.o ./bee/prog

petry@als02% cat ant/makefile

all:main.o
main.o:main.c ../bee/parse.h
        $(CC) -I../bee -c main.c

petry@als02% cat bee/makefile

OBJ=../ant/main.o parse.o
all:prog
prog:$(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ)
parse.o:parse.c
        $(CC) -c parse.c
```

If the top-level makefile has any issues pertaining to targets, dependencies or rules in the top-level makefile, the tool should be able to address/report the issues.
Google does not help. Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any graphical solution, however I find `make -n [options]` (or --just-print, --dry-run, --recon) pretty handy for debugging, which might be slightly helpful.

Comment: Thanks for commenting jdt. "make -n" would just print the commands that would be executed. I am looking for a tool which tells like "Your makefile is ok" if my makefile is fine, else, it should warn or report the bug/issues in the makefile.

Comment: There is nothing like that.  I don't even know what you mean by "any issues pertaining to targets, dependencies, or rules"... like what kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

i searched for "makefile linter" and found these two:

https://github.com/mrtazz/checkmake

https://github.com/softprops/mint

(as of 2019)

sadly both seem to be not developed actively.

"lint" has become the categorical name for software that statically checks for typical errors and questionable style. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)